# Grails 3 + Spring Security Core Plugin Confirm Password

Tags: grails, spring-security

Hello today I've started to learn Grails 3 with Spring Security Core Plugin but I'm having hard time with password Validation. When user is registering I want him to type password and confirmPassword. Everything would be ok if not hashing the password. I want my password to be encoded in database but with encoding I'm not able to compare those 2 passwords.

Here is my class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='username')
@ToString(includes='username', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    String confirmPass
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    User(String username, String password) {
        this()
        this.username = username
        this.password = password
        this.confirmPass = password
    }

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this)*.role
    }

    // because of that I can't compare password and confirmPass
    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false, size: 5..60, password: true, display: false, validator: { val, obj ->
            if (!obj.id && !obj.password) {
                return 'validation.user.password' // my message
            }
        }
        confirmPass blank: // now I'm stuck here, I've tried isPasswordValid() but won't work cuz of 'salt' What shout go here?
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }
}
```

What should I do to make it working(valid both password are same and then encoded password store in database).

Comment: What did you try already that isn't working?

Comment: tried to compare both passwords and using isPasswordValid() but no success.